# jquery dialog box overlapping with page contents

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-dialog

I have a jquery dialog box in my account page. When the dialog box is coming it is overlapping with the page contents. Please see the image here.

http://s7.postimg.org/dxsg3u417/Capture.png.

The code for dialog box is :

```
$('<div id="ratingloaderDiv"></div>').load("ratingDialog.jsp?id=" + id, function () {
    rateDialog = $(this).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        minHeight: 275,
        width: 400,
        height: 350,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var rating = 0;
            $('.rateCls' + id).rating({
                callback: function (value, link) {
                    rating = value;
                }
            });
            //more code goes.
```

Can anyone please suggest how to avoid overlapping with the page contents?

Comment: set z-index for the dialoag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the `z-index` of dialog box above the `z-index` of other content.

Ex:

```
body {
    z-index: 100;
}
.dialog {
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Comment: @user3681970 The code above shown is just an example of how you can solve the issue. Inspect the tabs that are showing in front of the modal and update the `z-index` of the dialog accordingly.